# $dy/dx$ problems, please help

Tags: calculus

Find $dy/dx$  given  $y\cos(xy)=3$.
Also find $dy/dx$ given $y=(2+\sin x)^{\cos x}$

I'm having a hard time solving for $dy/dx$  given $y\cos(xy)= 3$. Because of the $3$, wouldn't the right side of the equation equal $0$? And dividing $0$ by the derivative of the left side to get $dy/dx$ alone also equal $0$?

Also, I solved for $dy/dx$ as best as I could but when I checked using the Mathway app, it couldn't compute the solution.  So I have no way of checking to see if I'm on the right track.  For $dy/dx$ I got $(\cos^{2}x)/(2+\sin x) -\sin(x)\cdot\ln(2+\sin x)$ all multiplied by $y$.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not supposed to find when the derivative is equal to 3?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is the first sentence correct? Can you check this again?

Comment: The way I typed it is the way it's on the practice exam, if there was a typo on the exam when it was administered then I'm unable to tell what the original question was. I'll try the formatting tips, thank you Max.

Answer (score 1):

For $y\cos(xy)=3$ one must find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ by implicit differentiation. For students who find implicit differentiation difficult I recommend first considering both $x$ and $y$ as functions of some third variable such as $t$ and

$(1)$differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $t$,

$(2)$ multiply both sides by $dt$ then

$(3)$ divide both sides by $dx$

$(4)$ Solve the resulting equation for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(xy)\frac{dy}{dt}-y\sin(xy)\left(y\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}\right)&=&0\tag{1}\\
\cos(xy)dy-y\sin(xy)\left(y\,dx+x\,dy\right)&=&0\tag{2}\\
\cos(xy)\frac{dy}{dx}-y\sin(xy)\left(y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)&=&0\tag{3}\\
\left[\cos(xy)-xy\sin(xy)\right]\frac{dy}{dx}&=&y^2\sin(xy)\tag{4}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=&\dfrac{y^2\sin(xy)}{\cos(xy)-xy\sin(xy)}
\end{eqnarray}

You appear to have done the second problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving on $x$,

$$(y\cos(xy)-3)'=y'\cos(xy)-y\sin(xy)(y+xy')=0.$$

Then draw $y'$ from this equation.